# How can I make grid-item take the whole line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm learning grid-system and wondering how I can make some `grid-item` take remaining cells?

I have this 3 states:

1. Desktop
2. Mobile
3. Mobile without green one

[image]

I just set for the desktop:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
```

Works fine.
For the mobile, I reset the above code and do for the first element

```
grid-column: 1 / span 2
```

And receive what in the second option
But when it comes to the optional appearance of the green block, I get something like this:

[image: So not the third option]

So not the third option

The blue block takes only the half.
And I tried lots of grid things but didn't get the result I wanted.
With `flexbox` I could easily just use `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` properties, but with grid I'm doomed to pass some extra class, for example, `block__elem--without-green` and set `grid-column: 1/span2` by the blue block

Comment: At optional appearance give blue as complete `width` or let it span the same columns as red

Comment: Could you put the code into your question rather than just describe it - it makes it much easier to help.

Comment: @Rana The thing is if I set `grit-column: 1/span 2` for the blue block, then the green block, if it exists, will shift. So for that I need to pass some extra class defining if the green block exists, what I don't want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet takes advantage of the CSS grid-template-areas property.

The three divs are set to be in grid areas A, B, C respectively.

Their container has different layout depending on whether option 1, 2 or 3.

For the third layout the second div is just not displayed.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
  display: grid;
}

.container.one {
  grid-template-areas: 'A B C' 'A B C';
}

.container.two {
  grid-template-areas: 'A A' 'B C';
}

.container.three {
  grid-template-areas: 'A' 'C';
}

.container :nth-child(1) {
  border: red solid 1px;
  grid-area: A;
}

.container :nth-child(2) {
  border: green solid 1px;
  grid-area: B;
}

.container :nth-child(3) {
  border: blue solid 1px;
  grid-area: C;
}

.container.three :nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>ONE</h2>
<div class="container one">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<h2>TWO</h2>
<div class="container two">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<h2>THREE</h2>
<div class="container three">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that now I have to set extra classes. With flexbox, I could easily avoid that

Comment: You have to tell the system one way or another which layout you want. If it's not by a class then it's within each child's CSS property settings. I'm not sure why this is a problem, but if you could include your actual code in your question we might be able to advise better.